# Vue JS - How to change the background of a button when clicking on it using an object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, vuejs2

I have three buttons, I want to do this when you click on it, the background changed, for example, when you click on the red button, the background color changed to red, but here there is one important nuance if you click, for example, on the red button, and then another button, then the old color should disappear

For example, I clicked on the orange button, the background of the button turned orange, and then I clicked on the green button, then the orange background should disappear, You can also look at the [code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-newton-c2c3o)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(btn, index) in buttonCheckAge" :key="index" class="select-age">
      <div>
        <p>{{ btn.btnName }}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button :class="btn.className">{{ btn.btnText }}</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      buttonCheckAge: [
        {
          btnName: "Blue",
          btnText: "btn-Blue",
          className: "btn-teens",
          state: 0,
        },
        {
          btnName: "Red",
          btnText: "btn-Red",
          className: "btn-minxes",
          state: 1,
        },
        {
          btnName: "Green",
          btnText: "btn-Green",
          className: "btn-milfs",
          state: 2,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: where's the @click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `index` to track the selected button, apply a class based on the index, and style the button using the class:

1. Declare a data variable to track the selected index (named `selectedIndex`).

   ```js
   export default {
     data() {
       return {
         selectedIndex: -1,
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Use a [class binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-HTML-Classes) to conditionally add the `selected` class on the button.

   ```html
   <button :class="[btn.className, { selected: selectedIndex === index }]"
   ```
3. Add a `click`-handler that sets `selectedIndex` to the index of the button.

   ```html
   <button @click="selectedIndex = index">
   ```
4. Add a style for the buttons that combines `.selected` with the corresponding `btn.className`s:

   ```html
   <style scoped>
   .selected.btn-teens {
     background: #00f;
   }
   .selected.btn-minxes {
     background: #f00;
   }
   .selected.btn-milfs {
     background: #0f0;
   }
   </style>
   ```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/setting-background-color-of-button-fwnei?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

Answer (score 0):

I have made some this.$parent call but you can simply use provide/injection for this. Check the [code in sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-moser-or56u?file=/src/App.vue)

First, I made a `backgroundChooser()` method, that get the className of the pressed button, and bind a class name ("background-blue", or whatever) to a data() variable. This method exists in the App.vue component, and is called by an other method `chooser()`, in the HelloWorld.vue component.

Certainly there has other better ways to do this. Let us know if you find it.

*App.vue*

```
<template>
  <div id="app" :class="color">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" width="25%" />
    <HelloWorld msg="Hello Vue in CodeSandbox!" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      color: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    backgroundChooser(e) {
      if (e !== undefined) {
        if (e.currentTarget.className === "btn-teens") {
          this.color = "background-blue";
        } else if (e.currentTarget.className === "btn-minxes") {
          this.color = "background-red";
        } else if (e.currentTarget.className === "btn-milfs") {
          this.color = "background-green";
        }
      } else {
        this.color = "";
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.background-red {
  background-color: red;
}
.background-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.background-green {
  background-color: green;
}
</style>
```

*HelloWorld.vue*

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(btn, index) in buttonCheckAge" :key="index" class="select-age">
      <div>
        <p>{{ btn.btnName }}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button @click="chooser" :class="btn.className">
          {{ btn.btnText }}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    chooser(e) {
      this.$parent.backgroundChooser(e);
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      buttonCheckAge: [
        {
          btnName: "Blue",
          btnText: "btn-Blue",
          className: "btn-teens",
          state: 0,
        },
        {
          btnName: "Red",
          btnText: "btn-Red",
          className: "btn-minxes",
          state: 1,
        },
        {
          btnName: "Green",
          btnText: "btn-Green",
          className: "btn-milfs",
          state: 2,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Your code works, but I need to change the color of the button and not the block